# Why does gnu readline require me to hit control c twice?

Tags: haskell, readline

Normally, Control-C sends a sigint to a program, and kills it if it's not caught. The gnureadline library will install handlers for sigint. However, even when disabling those handlers in haskell, I still need to hit Control-C twice to kill a program. What's going on?

```
import System.Console.Readline

main = do 
        setCatchSignals False
        mainLoop


mainLoop = do
        maybeLine <- readline ">"
        case maybeLine of
            Nothing -> putStrLn ":("
            Just line -> do 
                            putStr line 
                            putStr " catch:"
                            catch <- getCatchSignals
                            putStrLn $ show $ catch
        mainLoop
```

Comment: This may be related to cooked/uncooked/rare terminal modes; `^C` does not always send a signal. It could be that readline causes a SIGTERM only on two sequential `^C`s.

Comment: Oh, interesting. I hadn't known that about terminal modes. I'll check and see if readline does something with that. Thank you.

Comment: I've expanded it slightly into an answer :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This may be related to the [cooked/uncooked/rare](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_terminal_interface#Early_Unices%3a_Seventh_Edition_Unix) terminal modes; `^C` does not always send a signal. It seems likely that readline uncooks the terminal, and thus any signals caused by keyboard input must be due to logic within readline itself; it seems plausible that it might only trigger a SIGINT on two sequential `^C`s (especially since for many programs that utilise readline such as shells and REPLs, the program exiting on a single `^C` would be very annoying!).

You might be able to change this behaviour by using the readline API to rebind `^C` to some of your own code that triggers a SIGINT. I haven't used readline from Haskell, just from C, so I'm not sure exactly how you'd go about this, but [the binding](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/readline/latest/doc/html/System-Console-Readline.html) seems rich enough to achieve it.